# calling a method not getting result

Tags: java, class, methods

so im just trying to print a random word and thats it

```
Dictionary secret = new Dictionary();        
    secret.getRandomWord();        
    System.out.println(secret);
```

^all that is in my main program.
And what was given to me that i have to use

```
 public String getRandomWord(){
    Random generator = new Random();
    String temp = new String();
    temp += dictionary[generator.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_WORDS)];
    return temp;
```

the above code is a class that was given to me that i have to work with. when i run my code i get `program3.Dictionary@a37368` when it should be a random word. Any ideas?

Comment: new for String is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
Dictionary secret = new Dictionary();
String randomWord = secret.getRandomWord();        
System.out.println(randomWord);
```

What you currently have is printing the result of `toString()` of the `Dictionary` object referenced by `secret`.

---

**EDIT**

Also possible without an extra variable:

```
Dictionary secret = new Dictionary();        
System.out.println(secret.getRandomWord());
```

Comment: thank you that fixed it, didnt realize i had to declare anothe variable

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the `Dictionary` object, Try to store the return type of `getRandomWord` method and print the same.

```
String secretStr = secret.getRandomWord();
System.out.println(secretStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you need change your code.

Instead of:

```
Dictionary secret = new Dictionary();        
    secret.getRandomWord();        
    System.out.println(secret);
```

use:

```
Dictionary secret = new Dictionary();    
String randomWord = secret.getRandomWord(); 
System.out.println(randomWord);
```

So, what's happen?